# VisualStudio API: include existing folder without recursively adding all the contents?

Tags: visual-studio, envdte, visual-studio-sdk, solution-explorer

Currently I'm using:

```
EntDTE.ProjectItems.AddFromDirectory()
```

to include the **existing** folder into VS project model, but this method includes into project all the contents of this folder too. Can folder can be simply added into project without adding all the subitems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not possible at all with current EnvDTE APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `EnvDTE.ProjectItems.AddFolder()` ? I think it'll just add a folder whether or not it exists and won't touch the content within the folder.

Comment: It simply fails to add folder because of physical folder existence... :(

Answer (score -1):

This code will include directory without content

```
dirPI = EntDTE.ProjectItems.AddFromDirectory(dirPath);
dirPI.ProjectItems.OfType<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>().ToList().ForEach(item =>
{
    item.Remove();
});
```

Comment: It's the ugliest solution I've ever see.